# Any way to denote (in back-end) channel entries that have been selected in a Matrix?

Tags: matrix

As an example, say I have an Authors channel, and I have an Authors List channel. The Authors channel contains a lot of biographical info on my writers; the Authors List channel lets me create a listing of writers like maybe "Fall 2013 Best-Selling Authors." The Authors List channel is primarily populated by use of its Matrix field, which is where you're picking the authors to list.

What would be really nice is if there is some way when looking at any author in the Authors channel's back end to tell if that Author is currently included in a Matrix field in that Authors List channel. So that I can bring up Donna Tartt and see that she was listed in my Authors List entries of "Fall 2013 Best-Selling Authors," "Fall 2002 Best-Selling Authors," "Winter 1993 Best-Selling Authors," and "Fall 1992 Best-Selling Authors."

This would save a ton of time and be much less error-prone vs our Plan B, which is having to create a big text field in the Authors channel and go in and manually note by hand each time we include an author in an Authors List.

Thanks!

(oh, forgot, while I'm asking for the moon: what would be REALLY awesome is if this automagically generated listing of Authors List entries could include both its entry and its date. rough dates are sort of inherent in my example Authors List entry titles above, but not in my actual data. thanks!)

Comment: haven't forgotten about this, just got pulled to another project. will be back on this one soon. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create a front-end admin template for these kind of elaborate info panels with links back to the control panel. The editor can browse on the front and see all info (in a more dense way than usually shown on a website) and click an entry he/she wants to edit.

Alternatively, for the control panel, you could maybe develop a module-tab or custom field that will generate a view of your desired data. I've seen there's an add-on called introvert, but don't know if that does work with related entries from inside a matrix. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/introvert

Comment: The feature request that had me posting this question has been dropped, now that it's been seen to be non-trivial. So I didn't actually do anything to create the functionality, but if I had, I probably would've written a custom PHP page with exactly the query I needed, along the lines of GDmac's first suggestion. (Boy, this feels like an anticlimactic resolution...) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know of none that work exactly like you;ve described but I have used [Zenbu](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zenbu) to great effect to filter/search entries.

Set it up how you like and then you can save the search criteria and you're away, very easy, quick and modestly priced.